# Is it possible to get ALL the changes in a sandbox? and how?

Tags: sandbox

Is it possible to get an admin/audit/other report on ALL changes that were made to a sandbox?

Assuming more than one person is working on a certain SB, I want to know what changes have been made and/or were not deployed.

- Custom objects
- Reports
- VF pages
- APEX classes/triggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tquila have released a pretty cool tool that lets you do a diff between 2 orgs. It's quicker than using eclipse.

It's very useful and lets you drill down to the exact changes. You can go right into the code to see the additions/removals just like a traditional Diff tool.

[Here it is](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/)

[image: Org Compare UI]

Answer (score 9):

Create a new project in eclipse force.com Ide with components like custom objects,reports,vf pages,apex.Then try to deploy the components to server(sandbox) to know the difference the between components in two sandbox instances.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also use Eclipse with the Force.com IDE for this type of comparison. You can gain more insight into *what changes are made* instead of just *which components are different* if you select two `src` folders and compare them with each other.

[image]

From there you will see a `Structure Compare` dialog, through which you can drill down to individual components and compare their source.

[image]